# How to include the third library in .arr with JCenter?

Tags: android, bintray, jcenter

In my android library project I include many third-party libraries like

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
// Java8的时间库
compile 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.3'
// RxJava
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.5'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0'
```

when I used `./gradlew install` build arr not include this third library. So my other project can't reference this library.

but when I include Rosie project (https://github.com/Karumi/Rosie). I can auto include `dagger`, `butterknife`....

How can I do it?

I want my library to include these third-party libraries in my arr.What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You must include these lines in your build.gradle to use Butterknife :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

Comment: No no no, I need my arr file include these third library. not my main project. Your method is let main project use butterknife.